# MacBook Pro - unable to connect mail to account Gmail

Tags: laptop, gmail, macbook-pro

I can't connect mail to the account Gmail from my Macbook Pro. Under Mail, I select preferences to ensure I have IMAP connected. But I'm still unsuccessful sending mail.

Comment: What's your sending server? If you get mail, but can't send that's the obvious issue. Should be `smtp.gmail.com`, using TLS (requires authentication) and it will want you login info again most likely.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable IMAP on the account.
In Gmail -> Settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP -> Enable IMAP